# ajax POST to servlet: null parameter

Tags: ajax, apache-flex, servlets, post

I'm working on a flex application and I need to call some data with a synchonous method. After some research, I've found a code from adobe that use ajax and external interface. That great.

[the code from adobe](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Synchronous_data_calling_with_Flex-7184.html)

When I send data with the GET method, the servlet read the parameters and print some infos (to check). But when I send data with the POST method, the servlet recieve the request, but the parameters disappeared.

**examples:**

SERVLET -- GET

```
System.out.println("recieved GET");
Map attrib = request.getParameterMap();
System.out.println("parameters: " + request.getParameterMap().size());
for(Object key: attrib.keySet()){
    System.out.println("key: "+key.toString() +" - "+attrib.get(key));
}
```

SERVLET -- POST

```
System.out.println("recieved POST");
Map attrib = request.getParameterMap();
System.out.println("parameters: " + request.getParameterMap().size());
for(Object key: attrib.keySet()){
    System.out.println("key: "+key.toString() +" - "+attrib.get(key));
}
```

FLEX GET METHOD

```
var ajax:Ajax = new Ajax(DATABASEURL + "?username=test);
ajax.requestType = AjaxRequestType.GET;
ajax.async = false;
var result:String = ajax.send();
```

printed by the servlet:

```
recieved GET
parameters: 1
key: username - [Ljava.lang.String;@4977e2
```

FLEX POST METHOD

```
var ajax:Ajax = new Ajax(DATABASEURL);
ajax.requestType = AjaxRequestType.POST;
ajax.async = false;
var result:String = ajax.send("username='test'");
```

printed by the servlet:

```
recieved POST
parameters: 0
```

What's wrong?

if the request is sent, why there is no parameter now?

If somebody can help me, that would be great, because I've so searched so much on google so that google could block me for spam.

**edit:** welcome can't be printed ?? So...

Comment: Why do you need a synchronous request? I suspect trying to use JavaScript in this way w/ a Flash app is just asking for trouble.

Comment: The application need to load some data from the servlet. The httpService object do it perfectly except a detail.... the result came from the result event. So the Class(data) that use This class(database) that use this httpService recieve a null object and when this class(database)recieve the result, it's too late. The class(data)already get a result. The wrong result, but a result anyway.
Calling with a synchronous way remove this problem. the function return the true value.

Comment: What are you talking about?! It's impossible to do a synchronous request without some serious implication on the front-end.  There's no *no reason whatsoever* to ever need a synchronous call to any back end service.  I think what you need to do is create a better architecture for what you're trying to do (which I still don't understand) instead of using a massive hack that in all probability will break something else later on...

Comment: @jax, I understand... But so, how can I load the configuration if the data that will be used by some classes are loaded independently, after the null result of the call ? All data used by the app come from the servlet. How can I do a "don't use this result while your children has not recieved the answer" ? It's why I've used a synchronous way. A call equal a result, not a null object and a true result later.... Is there a simple way to do something like this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's OK, I've found the problem.
It was the javascript code from the [adobe page](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Synchronous_data_calling_with_Flex-7184.html).

I've added

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

before the

```
xmlHttp.send(params);
```

and now, I've a good answer from the servlet...

```
recieved POST
parameters: 1
key: username - [Ljava.lang.String;@1cebc9f
```

It's pretty cool that wasn't using flex with javascript that bug, but only some missing requestReader.

Comment: There's no reason to be using ajax with Flex.  What's the point?!